# TypeError: defineCall is not a function. require() fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I've recently joined a project where a database model is built with Sequelize. However, I can't import more than a few files with *sequelize.import* before getting `TypeError: defineCall is not a function`. There seems to be errors using *require()* for importing the default function of certain files. I have the following structure:

**models/index.ts**

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

const sequelize = new Sequelize('mysql://root:password@localhost/myDatabase', {
    dialect: 'mysql',
    logging: false
});

const db: any = {};

fs.readdirSync(__dirname).filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== 'index.ts') && (file.endsWith('.js'));
}).forEach(file => {
    const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file)); //<<<<<<<<<< This brings an error
    db[model.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + model.name.slice(1)] = model;
});
```

and where it fails:

**sequelize.js**

```
  import(path) {
    // is it a relative path?
    if (Path.normalize(path) !== Path.resolve(path)) {
      // make path relative to the caller
      const callerFilename = Utils.stack()[1].getFileName();
      const callerPath = Path.dirname(callerFilename);
      path = Path.resolve(callerPath, path);
    }

    if (!this.importCache[path]) {
      let defineCall = arguments.length > 1 ? arguments[1] : require(path);

      if (typeof defineCall === 'object') {
        // ES6 module compatability
        defineCall = defineCall.default;
      }

      this.importCache[path] = defineCall(this, DataTypes);// <<<<<<<< defineCall is undefined here
    }

    return this.importCache[path];
  }
```

A typical file which results in an undefined defineCall:

**models/action-calls.js**

```
export default function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('actionCalls', {
        id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true, allowNull: false },
        actionId: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
        userId: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
        date: { type: DataTypes.DATE, allowNull: false },
        number: { type: DataTypes.STRING(32), allowNull: false },
        duration: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER }
    }, {
        tableName: 'ActionCalls',
        timestamps: false
    });
}
```

Oddly enough, sometimes this file gets imported without issues but then another file eventually gets the error. I've looked through all the files in the models/ folder, and they all follow the same pattern as *action-calls.js*. I had no problems with this until last week when it first appeared. My colleague has not experienced the error with the same codebase. I've tried going back to an earlier commit where it used to work but the error now stays. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's a syntax error in the first line of *sequelize.js*. I don't know if you're trying to use a function or actually importing a module.

Comment: import is a function in sequelize.js

Comment: I find it strange since `import` is a reserved keyword (meaning it cannot be used to name things) and even if it was a function, that's neither the syntax to define a function nor call it. Can you link to the documentation or show more code?

Comment: We're using an older version of Sequelize. The import function is deprecated in newer versions. https://sequelize.org/master/manual/models-definition.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the problem was with ts-node-dev. After updating it from 1.0.0-pre.49 to 1.1.6 the error disappeared.